# Object complements with/without "to be"

Tags: object-complements

I come across sentences like

```
[1] I consider it a failure.
[2] Scientists belived it to be a hoax.
```

The object complement in the first is "a failure" and in the second is "to be a hoax". But what if we interchange these complements?

```
[3] I consider it to be a failure.
[4] Scientists belived it a hoax.
```

Are the last two correct? What is the grammatical/meaning difference between these two kind of sentences?

Comment: In [1], the NP "a failure" is indeed the objective predicative complement (PC) of "consider". But in [2] the PC is not the subordinate clause "to be a hoax" but just the NP "a hoax". Object complements consist of NPs and AdjPs but not clauses. Some grammars have an analysis of "a failure" in [1] and "a hoax" in [4] as verbless clauses (technically 'small clauses'). Semantically, [1] and [3] are the same, as are [2] and [4].

Comment: "Object complements consist of NPs and AdjPs". But what about the infinitival clause "say" in "Brienne heard herself say". Once you said that "say" is a complement of "heard". It is neither NPs nor AdjPS. And what about "Brienne heard herself say it". What kind of complements are "say" and "it" there?

Comment: Yes, in _Brienne heard herself say_  "say" is complement of "heard". It's not an objective predicative complement, though, but a catenative complement. In _Brienne heard herself say it_, the subordinate clause "say it" is complement of "heard", and "it" is direct object of "say".

Comment: What is the difference between kinds of complement "that she say it" in "Brienne heard that she say it" and "say it" in "Brienne heard herself say it"? In both examples the complements presented by subordinate clause. In both examples the complements are of the same "heard". What the difference between kinds of complement "she say it" and "say it"?

Comment: "objective predicative complement", ain't too many of those via google.

Comment: @xyz I think you're drifting off topic. Your original question was about object complements, which I've answered. FYI, the main difference is that the subordinate clause "say it" is non-finite, while the _that_ clause is finite, at least it would be if you changed the verb to the correct form, i.e. "says" or "said".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [1] *I consider it a failure.*
>
> [2] *Scientists believed it to be a hoax.*
>
> [3] *I consider it to be a failure.*
>
> [4] *Scientists believed it a hoax*.

In [1], the NP "a failure" is indeed the objective predicative complement (PC) of "consider". But in [2] the PC is not the subordinate clause "to be a hoax" but just the NP "a hoax". Object complements consist of NPs and AdjPs but not clauses.

Some grammars have an analysis of "a failure" in [1] and "a hoax" in [4] as verbless clauses (technically 'small clauses').

[1] and [3] have the same meaning, as do [2] and [4].